# In magento how to display associated products image in grouped products page

Tags: magento

[image]I have created a group associated with 3 products and now i need to display the individual images for each associated product in the grouped product page and make the customer to select any associated product from the group and add it to his cart.

Answer (score 0):

Please proceed as follows :

Open app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

If this is not present copy this file from base folder and place it at exact folder path in your theme.

Go to line 50 and add following

```
<th></th>
```

before

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
```

then go to line no 64 and add

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a></td>
```

before

```
<td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
```

Done, this will add a new td into your product details page and also add image of the related products where they are listed.

Hope this helps you.

### Update Again

Please change your app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

with the content below:

```
<?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_hasAssociatedProducts); exit; ?>
        <?php $_collectionSize = count($_associatedProducts) ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = 3; ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php else: ?>
       <div><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
```

This will show you the products block one by one just as on category listing page.. obviously you need to call grouped.phtml in outer div so that these blocks comes under the main product... currently they are coming in the right area adjacent to Main product image.

Also you need to apply css as you need.

Thanks hope this clears.

Comment: Yes i can get the image with in the table if i add this code but i need to customize the entire grouped products page and have to display image alone with title like we are displaying all the products in category page.@SKV

Comment: I need to redesign my grouped product page like my category page.@SKV

Comment: Priya, you can copy the grid layout HTML from app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml into the loop on grouped.phtml. do not forget to change the object for products loop.. this suggestion is in order to start to achieve what you want.

Comment: can u please explain it briefly where i need to copy my view.phtml .how to  change the objects for products loop?@SKV

Comment: I need to display in grid view not as a list view.Kindly find my attached image.I need to display the products like mentioned in the attachment.I dont want to display the description.@SKV

Comment: Priya as i told you you need to fetch the above files content into correct div so this will be placed below the grouped product description.. also you can remove or add/change anything or css as per you need.. i need to have your sites access :) after this..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44756/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-skv)

Comment: w8 for some time, going for a meeting

Answer (score 0):

Replace `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml` with the following code.

```
<?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Image'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(35); ?>" width="35" height="35" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_item, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
            <td class="a-right">
                <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <td class="a-center">
            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('super-product-table')</script>
```